# Why can't I retag when improving a suggested edit?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I came upon [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7592540) in the Suggested Edits queue on SO, and decided I ought to improve the given edit by just tagging the question with [python] rather than adding a syntax-highlighter hint. But I couldn't! There's no option for me to change the question's tags when improving the suggested edit (nor when rejecting-and-editing).

[image]

Is this a bug, or is there a reason that we can't retag when improving a suggested edit?

Comment: I do have it, maybe it needs 10k, like the inline tag editor

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hm, that could be it. I only have up to the 3000-rep tier of privileges on SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is a moron.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you're not improving an edit to a *question*. That's actually an answer posted to the following question: [Looping in a spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral) - It has also since been deleted by the owner.

Comment: My god am I dumb.

Comment: In my defense, the review queue listed the tags beneath the post body, which is what duped me into thinking that was a question rather than an answer.